# Iterating through a dictionary contains both dict and array

Tags: django, python-2.7

Can any one please help me iterate through the below dictionary?

```
productDict = {
    32L: {
        'width': [9.0, 12.0], 
        'depth': [2,4,6], 
        'height': [5.0,6.0,7.0]
    }, 
    31L: {
        'width': [25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0], 
        'depth': [], 
        'height': []
    }
}
```

`32L` and `31L` are the id of the products. Each product has width, depth and height...

Comment: What is it you want to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
>>> for key, value in productDict.iteritems():
...      for key2, value2 in value.iteritems():
...                print key2, value2
... 
width [9.0, 12.0]
depth [2, 4, 6]
height [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
width [25.0, 30.0, 35.0, 40.0]
depth []
height []
```

Comment: can you iterate this in django template

Comment: Almost the exact same way. See Timmys answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for key, l in productDict.items %}
     {{ key }}
     {% for val in l %}
         {{ val }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
     {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

[`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) django template tag (notice that you use `.items` to emulate python's `.iteritems()` on a dictionary)